# Can an acid or base have a pH less than 0 or more than 14?

Tags: acid-base, ph

This question has been asked earlier, but I could not understand it.
Please, someone explain it in an easier way.

Comment: Also http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25155/can-a-negative-ph-exist and http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6997/ph-range-outside-convetional-0-14

Comment: It was asked many times, you should read more answers and if you still don't get it, tell what's your problem otherwise I doubt you could get answer useful for you.